# Communicate via Bluetooth from iOS (and Android) to Windows without pairing

Tags: android, ios, windows, bluetooth

I have searched extensively, and fear the answer is no, but is the statement in the title possible?

Here is the scenario: Customers approach a kiosk that has an iBeacon in it. The customers phone detects the iBeacon, and presents the customer with the option to confirm to the kiosk that it's really them, and thus the kiosk can retrieve their details from the cloud. The issue I have is that confirmation - sending something back from the device (iOS or Android) to the kiosk (Windows) without the internet, and without bluetooth pairing. There could be 10,000 kiosks and millions of users, so pairing is really not viable.

From what I have read, Android and Windows support SPP, and can send and receive unauthenticated packets between them - but iOS does not support SPP.

iOS could set itself up as a peripheral, but in all my searching I cannot find a way to make Windows a central to be able to detect it. I've tried 32 feet, I have a Broadcomm BLE 4.0 dongle, but alas all I get is "No widcomm.". Even though I have Windows 8.1 with BLE API support - it seems it's only for Metro apps (or App Store apps), and I am not building either.

Anyone aware of a means to achieve what I need? Or am I right that it's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually establish a BLE connection between iOS/Android with windows 8 without manually pairing in the Bluetooth Settings system UI.

As far as I know windows only supports the central/client mode, so you will not be able to run it in the peripheral/server mode.